# File names not displayed on tabs in Goland

Tags: intellij-idea

For some reason I can no longer see the file names on my open tabs in Goland:
[Goland no tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KijqF.png)

I can't seem to drag the row down to make the row taller.

Whereas in IntelliJ, it works as expected:
[IntelliJ with tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DBEk.png)

I'm using Material theme (palenight) in both.
It seems to be a problem in 2019.2.1 - I've rolled back to 2019.2 and my tabs are back :)

Comment: Have you tried other themes? Maybe your theme is broken in Goland.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling/uninstalling the theme and see if the problem is still there.
Also, check your settings via Find Action, if "Tab placement" is not set to "None".